# How to require custom attribute from base class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a base class that I would like all derived classes to put an attribute on top of the class like this:

```
[MyAttribute("Abc 123")]
public class SomeClass : MyBaseClass
{
  public SomeClass() : base()
  {
  }
}


public class MyBaseClass
{
  public string PropA { get; set; }

  public MyBaseClass()
  {
    this.PropA = //ATTRIBUTE VALUE OF DERIVED
  }
}
```

How do I enforce that derived classes need the attribute, then use the attribute value in the base constructor?

Comment: Can you give a little more background information?  I'm wondering if something like an abstract property could perform the same function in a more robust way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe instead of using custom attribute use abstract class with abstract property. Using this method you ensure that every non-abstract derived class will implement this property. Simple example is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx)

Comment: Agree with this answer. You should use Abstract properties or have your base class constructor take a parameter. This way, your derived classes have to provide the base class with a value for the parameter. Using a constructor parameter is no different to using an attribute in your case.

Comment: It would be interesting to explore combining this with the `Required` attribute, @TruMan1.  See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You can throw exception in constructor if a certain attribute is not found.

Sample :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass obj =new MyClass();
}

public class MyClassBase
{
    public MyClassBase()
    {
        bool hasAttribute = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Any(attr => attr != null);

        // as per 'leppie' suggestion you can also check for attribute in better way
        // bool hasAttribute = Attribute.IsDefined(GetType(), typeof(MyAttribute));
        if (!hasAttribute)
        {
            throw new AttributeNotApplied("MyClass");
        }
    }
}

[MyAttribute("Hello")]
class MyClass : MyClassBase
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }
}

internal class AttributeNotApplied : Exception
{
    public AttributeNotApplied(string message) : base(message)
    {

    }
}

internal class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(string msg)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What AppDeveloper said, but instead of that monstrosity of code, use

```
bool hasAttribute = Attribute.IsDefined(GetType(), typeof(MyAttribute));
```

Comment: thanks! I have never checked the Attribute class properly, never knew that method existed

Comment: @AppDeveloper: It is something I also never spotted initially till I started playing with attributes heavily :)

Comment: @AppDeveloper: Pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to force the use of an attribute in C# at compile time. You could check the presence of the attribute at runtime using reflection, but that could be worked around if someone catches the exceptions correctly.